# Disable opening PDFs inline in Safari 5.1

Tags: safari, macos

In Safari 5.0 or below it's very easy to disable opening pdfs inline, you simply say

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitOmitPDFSupport -bool YES
```

and it never bothers you again.

In Safari 5.1 this no longer works. Does anyone know an alternative to prevent Safari 5.1 opening PDFs in the browser rather than as a download and then in Preview?

Comment: @Peter, @chiggsy: Discussion about Apple beta or pre-release software is not allowed because doing so is restricted by their NDA required to use it and answers are subject to change and not officially supported. I agree it is inconvenient, but there are valid reasons for not allowing discussions of pre-release software (of any company's, not just Apple's). If you wish to discuss this further, then I suggest opening a topic in Meta.

Comment: @Philip: thanks for the details. Sounds reasonable.

Comment: The other main reason that we don't allow questions about prerelease software is that they are usually too localized. Things change quickly in that world, so questions about prerelease software grow stale quickly.